# Base64 encoded image sent using sendgrid not displayed in mails

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

I am trying to send a logo image in the HTML using sendGrid mailing service. I went through a lot of articles and tried a lot but still could not figure out on how to display inline image using content_id.

I went through following links but still could not make it work:
[Link1][1]: https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/
[Link2][2]: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/issues/841
Few of the answers suggest to add image as a base64 string in HTML but that does not work with few web mailing clients.

Here is my code:
`

```
    try
    {

        const msg = {
            to: `${customerData.raw[0].invoicemail}`, // List of receivers email address
            from : 'xxxx@xxx.com',
            subject: `${subject}`, // Subject line
            html: emailData, // HTML body content
            attachments:
            [
            {filename:`${filename}`,content:invoice,type:"application/pdf"},
            {filename:'logo.jpg',content:logoImageData,content_id:'logo',type:"image/jpg",disposition:"inline"}
            ],
            }
            sgMail.send(msg)
            //return this.mailerService.sendEmail(msg)
    }
    catch
    {
        return false
    }`
```

And here is the HTML block:

```
<img src = "content_id:logo" alt = "Logo Image" width=140 height=20>
```

Also, the image is being received as an attachment but is not displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the very late reply, I've also had trouble getting my image to display using SendGrid.

@Abhijeet, have you tried replacing `src = "content_id:logo"` with `src="cid:logo"`?

For other beginners, like myself, using SendGrid I will include the other steps that @Abhijeet already has done.

1. Upload and convert your image file to base64 (we'll call this **logoImageData**).
2. We want to replace the beginning of the base64 encoded image string using `String.prototype.replace()`.

```
export const cleanLogoImageData = logoImageData.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,' , '')
```

3. Now, in the attachments for mail data for SendGrid, you need to add these to your object: `filename`, `content`, `contentType`, `content_id`, and `disposition`.

```
const msg = {
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: "logo.jpg",
      content: cleanLogoImageData,
      contentType: "image/jpeg",
      content_id: "logo",
      disposition: "inline",
    },
  ],
}
```

`content_id` and `disposition: "inline"` are what got my logo to show.

4. Finally, in the html file holding your `<img />`, you must set the `src` as `cid:logo` or whatever your `content_id` is. And moreover, it's recommended to add `align="top"` and `display: block` in your img tag for better and consistent cross-platform email display of the image.

```
<img align="top"
     style="display: block"
     src="cid:logo"
     alt="company logo"
/>
```